# jax-rs retrieve form parameters

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, jax-rs

I'm trying to retrieve some parameters that are passed to jax-rs from a posted form with the HttpServletRequest. However, my request object is always returning null values for my parameters. Am I not going about this the right way? I've posted the code below, along with an example request that is getting sent.

Here is my service:

```
@Path("/")
@Stateless
public class HomeController {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @Context
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    @EJB
    private LoginServiceLocal loginService;

    @POST
    @Path("/authenticate")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public void authenticate() throws Exception {
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        if (loginService.authenticate(email, password)) {
            response.sendRedirect("/app");
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("authenticationError", "Invalid email/password.");

        }
    }
}
```

Example request:

```
POST http://localhost:8081/cheetah-web/authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026    Firefox/3.6.12
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:8081/cheetah-web/login
Cookie: JSESSIONID=a4e7aec0624206ad33754e35cce4
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 39

email=unit%40test.com&password=testpass
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
@POST
@Path("/authenticate")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void authenticate(@FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("password") String password) throws Exception {

    if (loginService.authenticate(email, password)) {
        response.sendRedirect("/app");
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("authenticationError", "Invalid email/password.");

    }
}
```

Comment: How to retrieve all form params at once like we can do for query params using UriInfo.getQueryParameters()

Comment: You would use a MultivaluedMap as a parameter. For example, public void authenticate(MultivaluedMap<String, String> form) { ... }