# Spring POST not returning valid numbers

Tags: java, javascript, spring, angularjs

I am extremely new to spring, but I managed to come up with this code from my javascript

```
$scope.addMe = function(){
        var params = {
            date :111111,
            username: 'thisGuy',
            notetext: 'this is a new note that was just added'
        };
        $http.post(afHttp.baseUrl + "/blah/" + $scope.dog.id, {params: params})
            .success(function(data) {
            });
    }
```

and in elclipe I have

```
@POST
@Path("/{id}")
public void getAddMssg(@PathParam("id") int id, @FormParam("date") int date, @FormParam("username") String username, @FormParam("notetext") String notetext) {
    System.out.println("date:      "+date);
    System.out.println("username:   "+ username);
    System.out.println("notetext:   "+ notetext);
    System.out.println("id:   "+ id);

}
```

And when I look at my console log in eclipse it says

```
date:   0
username:   null
notetext:   null
id:   123124
```

What am I doing wrong?  I have been working on this for awhile with no avail.  Can someone please help?

Oh sorry I forgot to add I am using angularjs.

Answer (score 2):

Pass params into that argument, not {params:params}.
Also, add the Content-Type header as the third argument:

```
$http.post(afHttp.baseUrl + "/blah/" + $scope.dog.id, params, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
```

And on the server-side, proceed @POST with @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED):

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
```

The fully qualified name for MediaType is javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType, in case you need to import it.

Comment: yes, I say that, see my comment, and user say that result is zero

Comment: I certainly am not an expert, but I want to figure this out.  See if my latest update works please.

Comment: Okay, thanks, so I added that and got the error "(Unsupported Media Type)" when adding that

Comment: Made updates based on the example I saw here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234084/jax-rs-retrieve-form-parameters

Answer (score 1):

what is $http?
if it is jQuery, post method need 'data' not "params".
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I am using angularjs, sorry about that.

Comment: ok, that is a error: replace {params:params} with params only:
[link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#methods_post)

post(url, data, config)

Comment: I don't quite undestand, can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Oh sorry I was looking at the wrong thing, what would config be though?

Comment: $http.post(afHttp.baseUrl + "/blah/" + $scope.dog.id, params)
            .success(function(data) {
            });

In AngularjS post methot take second parameter data object, you send other object with name param. I think so is all right.
Third parameter is optional. Not needed for you.

Comment: Yeah, I am still getting 0's and nulls

Comment: ok, add " HttpServletRequest request" as last parameter in java method and debug what is in. In _parameters variable. Sorry now i can't create a project to test that.

Comment: Can you elaberate on what you mean/ example?  I have been googling HttpServletRequest request and I have not come up with anything that uses it as a java param.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504258/spring-3-mvc-accessing-httprequest-from-controller)
I mean that:
public void getAddMssg(@PathParam("id") int id, @FormParam("date") int date, @FormParam("username") String username, @FormParam("notetext") String notetext, HttpServletRequest request) {...

Show us, please, new code for javascript function?

Comment: Am I suppose to use it in the body too?

Comment: debug it, set a breakpoint in first line in body, and see what is in

Comment: I have never really used debug before, but here are the errors I got for running it and putting a breaker on the first line: SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Exception obtaining parameters               and                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40048/discussion-between-baltov-and-alex-wilhelm)