# Why am I getting response status of 204 No content in my REST server?

Tags: java, rest, server, jersey

I am new to REST API and working with servers in general and I am trying to make a simple client-server application. I am using Jersey.

Client sends some data to server, server receives the data and shows it on the desired uri and vice versa.

The vice-versa part of receiving the data hosted on server is working fine, but I am not able to send data to server.

I have tried POST like this:

```java
    @POST
    @Path("/something")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public void getSomething(){

    }
```

And my client side code looks something like this:

```java
Client client = Client.create();
MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
        formData.add("name1", "val1");
        formData.add("name2", "val2");

        WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/artifact/rest/something");

        ClientResponse response = resource.type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(ClientResponse.class, formData);

        System.out.println(response);
```

I am trying to send a string or json type object to server and it should show it on that url. But I am not able to do so.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me in this.

**Edit**
I would also appreciate if someone could tell me how to send data to server with code like this.

Comment: Is the URL you're hitting correct? I can see the post method evoking on "/something" but your URL is pointing to "/artifact/rest/something". Have you given a default URL path before /something in your code?

Comment: Yes @SamyakJain the url is correct. That part of url is added in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format for the jersey server side although whatever you are using is the same:

```
@POST
@Path("your path")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
```

For the client side, try using this.

```
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url + "/rest/something");
    post.addHeader("Accept" , "application/json");
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1", "val1"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name2", "val2"));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
    String out = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getSomething` is not returning anything. This translates to a [`204 No Content`](https://httpstatuses.com/204) response: The operation was successful (the `2xx` of the code indicates this) but there is nothing to return.

If you want to return something, change the return type from `void` to [`Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html).

```
@POST
@Path("/something")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response getSomething() {
  return Response.ok("Success!").build();
}
```

This will return the HTTP status code [`200 OK`](https://httpstatuses.com/200) with `Success!` as the content of the response body.

But you probably want to somehow *use* the content of the request. Take a look at [jax-rs retrieve form parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234084/jax-rs-retrieve-form-parameters) for how you can do this.